# SQL Get most frequent value from a column based on a condition

Tags: mysql, sql

This query

```
SELECT 
PlayerID, HeroTypeID, HeroTypeIDCount, Wins / (Losses + Wins) AS WinRate, Wins, Losses
FROM (
    SELECT E.PlayerID AS PlayerID, 
           FK_HeroTypeID AS HeroTypeID, 
           COUNT(FK_HeroTypeID) AS HeroTypeIDCount,
           SUM(CASE WHEN D.Result = 'LOSS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Losses, 
           SUM(CASE WHEN D.Result = 'WIN' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Wins
        FROM GamePlayerDetail D
        JOIN Player E
            ON D.FK_PlayerID = E.PlayerID
        JOIN Game I
                ON D.FK_GameID = I.GameID
        WHERE PlayedDate BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND CURDATE()
    GROUP BY E.PlayerID, FK_HeroTypeID
) AS T
ORDER BY PlayerID
```

produces the following result:

```
# PlayerID, HeroTypeID, HeroTypeIDCount, WinRate, Wins, Losses
'1', '11', '1', '1.0000', '1', '0'
'1', '13', '3', '0.3333', '1', '2'
'1', '24', '5', '0.8000', '4', '1'
'1', '27', '1', '1.0000', '1', '0'
'2', '28', '1', '0.0000', '0', '1'
'2', '6', '1', '0.0000', '0', '1'
'2', '30', '1', '0.0000', '0', '1'
'2', '7', '1', '1.0000', '1', '0'
```

What I'd like to do is get the most frequent FK_HeroTypeID (which is also highest value of HeroTypeIDCount) per PlayerID, but in case of ties, the highest winrate should take precedence. Here's an example of what I'd like to get:

```
PlayerID, HeroTypeID, HeroTypeIDCount, WinRate, Wins, Losses
       1,         24,               5,  0.8000,    4,      1
       2,          7,               1,  1.0000,    1,      0
```

How should you write a query like this?

Edit:

Ok, here's a simple Create/Insert table for the produced result.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d644a

Comment: A result set without a data set is like a stick without a lollipop. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Alright, I've went ahead and edited the question to include sqlfiddle link for create/insert statement for above produced result.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand, but for playerID 1 the highest winrate is for 11 and 27, not 24. Right?

Comment: @JoeTaras The precedence for display is 1) Highest value of HeroTypeIDCount. Then 2) Highest winrate, which only should matter in case of ties in HeroTypeIDCount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT playerid
     , herotypeid
     , herotypeidcount
     , winrate
     , wins
     , losses 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT *
            , CASE WHEN @prev=playerid THEN @i:=@i+1 ELSE @i:=1 END rank
            , @prev:=playerid prev 
         FROM table1
            , (SELECT @prev:=null,@i:=0) vars 
        ORDER 
           BY herotypeidcount DESC
            , winrate DESC
     ) x 
 WHERE rank = 1;
```

Here's a 'hack' solution. It works, but really shouldn't be relied upon...

```
 SELECT * 
   FROM 
      ( SELECT * 
          FROM table1 
         ORDER 
            BY herotypeidcount DESC
             , winrate DESC
      ) x
  GROUP 
     BY playerid
```